# HTML textarea margin

Tags: html, css, web-applications

When I add a margin to an HTML [<textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) that has 100% width, the margin is properly applied to the left side, but the entire textbox is shifted to the right and extends of the parent container.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTnCd/) as an example:

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 10px;">tyjyjyj</textarea>
```

As you can see, the textarea extends past the right side instead of expanding to the 10 pixels margin. Is there a way to fix this?

The only way I can think of is by manually adjusting the size with JavaScript, but there must be another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the effect you're after. Here I am setting the position to absolute and giving the margin from each edge.

**HTML**

```html
<textarea>tyjyjyj</textarea>
```

**CSS**

```css
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

In effect: http://jsfiddle.net/tTnCd/3/

And to better position the textarea you can wrap it with relative styled elements like so http://jsfiddle.net/tTnCd/4/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 100% width on an element that does not use 100% width of the parent.
In that case, you need to create a max-width of 100% and then try getting a width value that corresponds well having into account the margin that you are applying.

Answer (score 0):

When you set *width:100%*, it is set 100% to the parent but when you add the extra 10 pixels margin, it is now entirely bigger than the parent.

I have started to use percentages over any fixed margin or width so this doesn't occur.

So try something like *width:99%; margin:10px 0.5%;* which will not overflow the parent element assuming nothing else like padding or border is being applied.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTnCd/1/) updated to use a percentage margin and width as to not overflow:

```
<textarea style="width: 99%; height: 100%; margin: 10px 0.5% 10px 0.5%;">tyjyjyj</textarea>
```

I do want to add though any border or padding on the element, when it has 100% width, will also make it overflow. An example is the default styling in Firefox for the textarea. It gives it a 2 pixels inset border + the width + the margin.