# Why won't my textarea be centered exactly in the middle?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm trying to make a typing test and I'm having trouble trying to make the textarea exactly in the center. I've tried align-items, align-self, align-content, but nothing works. Here's what my code looks like:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Impact";

}

body{
    background-color: grey;
}

.container{
    width: 80vmin;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px;
}

.stats{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

textarea{
    align-content: center;
    resize: none; 
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:20px
}

button{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;

}

button:hover{
    background-color:rgb(66, 154, 209)
}

button:active{
    background:#003659
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My Typing Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="stats">
                <p>Time: <span id="time">0s</span></p>
                <p>WPM: <span id="wpm">0</span></p>
            </div>

            <div id="words" onmousedown="return false"
            onselect="return false">
            </div>

            <textarea rows="3"></textarea>

            <div class= "ButtonControl">
                <button id= "Start Timer">Start Test</button>
                <button id= "Reload Page">Reset Test</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="Test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I center the textarea even if the user tries to resize the window?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333594/html-textarea-margin).

Comment: use flexbox, ill send da code in a couple  minns

Answer (score 0):

Your `textarea` didn't work because of margin.
You set `width: 100%;` and `margin: 20px;`, so the `textarea` went 20px left.

You can solve it by removing `margin: 20px`(First example) or adding new div that has `20px padding` and contains `textarea`.(Second example).

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Impact";

}

body{
    background-color: grey;
}

.container{
    width: 80vmin;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px;
}

.stats{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

textarea{
    align-content: center;
    resize: none; 
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

button{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;

}

button:hover{
    background-color:rgb(66, 154, 209)
}

button:active{
    background:#003659
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My Typing Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="stats">
                <p>Time: <span id="time">0s</span></p>
                <p>WPM: <span id="wpm">0</span></p>
            </div>

            <div id="words" onmousedown="return false"
            onselect="return false">
            </div>

            <textarea rows="3"></textarea>

            <div class= "ButtonControl">
                <button id= "Start Timer">Start Test</button>
                <button id= "Reload Page">Reset Test</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="Test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Impact";

}

body{
    background-color: grey;
}

.container{
    width: 80vmin;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px;
}

.stats{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.TextControl {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

textarea{
    align-content: center;
    resize: none; 
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

button{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;

}

button:hover{
    background-color:rgb(66, 154, 209)
}

button:active{
    background:#003659
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My Typing Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="stats">
                <p>Time: <span id="time">0s</span></p>
                <p>WPM: <span id="wpm">0</span></p>
            </div>

            <div id="words" onmousedown="return false"
            onselect="return false">
            </div>

            <div class="TextControl"><textarea rows="3"></textarea></div>

            <div class= "ButtonControl">
                <button id= "Start Timer">Start Test</button>
                <button id= "Reload Page">Reset Test</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="Test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically made a flex container around the text area, and centered all its contents

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Impact";

}

body{
    background-color: grey;
}

.container{
    width: 80vmin;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px;
}

.stats{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

textarea{
    align-content: center;
    resize: none; 
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:20px
}
                   /* new code here */
          .testbox{
        display: flex; 
          align-items: center;
        justify-content: center; }
     button{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: gold;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;

       }

         button:hover{
    background-color:rgb(66, 154, 209)
      }

             button:active{
    background:#003659
             }
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My Typing Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="stats">
                <p>Time: <span id="time">0s</span></p>
                <p>WPM: <span id="wpm">0</span></p>
            </div>

            <div id="words" onmousedown="return false"
            onselect="return false">
            </div>
                     
               <!-- new code here -->      <div class="testbox" >  <textarea 
                    rows="3"></textarea>  </div>

            <div class= "ButtonControl">
                <button id= "Start Timer">Start Test</button>
                <button id= "Reload Page">Reset Test</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="Test.js"></script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: works for me, u should use this

Answer (score 0):

try to use in the container with position: relative
and position absolute in the texterea,
then you can define left: some px...